# Difference between Solr, SolrCloud directory structure

Tags: solr, lucene, cloudera, solrcloud, cloudera-manager

I've practiced the Solr tutorials to index files. For this I used, `solr`, `post` scripts in `solr/bin` directory. Directory structure of Solr is as follows:

[image]

Recently we got SolrCloud on Cloudera Manager. The directory structure is completely different. There are no `solr`, `post` scripts in `solr/bin` directory.

[image]

[image]

Can someone please explain me how can I use `solr`, `post` scripts on SolrCloud?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try searching for the file?

Comment: Yes, I searched for the files in the entire installation directory `solr/`. But there are no such files. Also, I couldn't find any information about the SolrCloud directory structure on Google.

Comment: You'd be better off contacting cloudera support for this, because they have clearly customized the entire setup, and hence it'll also be difficult to get any meaningful information on Google or SO.

Comment: You are correct. I've gone through the Cloudera Search documentation and understood the concepts. Thank you for the suggestion :)